# open source music streaming api

Tags: api, streaming, pervasive

I would like to stream music (not random, specific...e.g if i want *megadeth - peace sells* i should be able to stream it) to the clients from the server. **grooveshark** came to my mind first, but it doesn't have an open api that i can use. do you know any facilities like grooveshark that has an open api?

Answer (score 1):

I found links to a [GrooveShark API](http://developers.grooveshark.com/docs/public_api/v3/) on their site.  Interesting API calls that seem to do what you want include...

```
addUserLibrarySongs
getUserPlaylists
subscribePlaylist
getUserLibrarySongs
getUserFavoriteSongs
addUserFavoriteSong
getPlaylistSongs
getPlaylistInfo
setPlaylistSongs
createPlaylist
getDoesSongExist
getArtistsInfo
getAlbumsInfo
Search
getPlaylistSearchResults
getSongSearchResults
getSongURLFromSongID
getPlaylistURLFromPlaylistID
getTrialInfo
```

Comment: Groovshark is no longer available